# XML update with powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I have the following sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>        
<SQLUsers>
      <SQLFile>
        <FileVersion>260</FileVersion>
        <FileDate>06.14.2014</FileDate>
      </SQLFile>
      <SQLAccount>
        <user001>
          <AccountName>user001</AccountName>
          <SQLSysAdmin>Adm_user001</SQLSysAdmin>
          <SQLSysAdminPassword>P@ssw0rd</SQLSysAdminPassword>
          <SQLReadOnlyUser>user004</SQLReadOnlyUser>
          <SQLReadOnlyUserPassword>P@ssw0rd</SQLReadOnlyUserPassword>
          <CreationDate>06.13.2014</CreationDate>
          <InstanceID>InstanceID</InstanceID>
        </user001>
      </SQLAccount>
      <SQLAccount>
        <user002>
          <AccountName>user002</AccountName>
          <SQLSysAdmin>Adm_user001</SQLSysAdmin>
          <SQLSysAdminPassword>P@ssw0rd</SQLSysAdminPassword>
          <SQLReadOnlyUser>user005</SQLReadOnlyUser>
          <SQLReadOnlyUserPassword>P@ssw0rd</SQLReadOnlyUserPassword>
          <CreationDate>06.13.2014</CreationDate>
          <InstanceID>InstanceID</InstanceID>
         </user002>
      </SQLAccount>
    </SQLUsers>
```

I should update this XML file, to add a new element under the "UserXXX" node. something like this:

```
<user002>
    <AccountName>user002</AccountName>
    <SQLSysAdmin>Adm_user001</SQLSysAdmin>
    <SQLSysAdminPassword>P@ssw0rd</SQLSysAdminPassword>
    <SQLReadOnlyUser>user005</SQLReadOnlyUser>
    <SQLReadOnlyUserPassword>P@ssw0rd</SQLReadOnlyUserPassword>
    <CreationDate>06.13.2014</CreationDate>
    <InstanceID>InstanceID</InstanceID>
    <DatabaseName>database1</DatabaseName>
    <DatabaseName>database2</DatabaseName>
 </user002>
```

I have the following powershell script, which accept the Username, and the database name as parameter:

```
param($accountName,$database)

$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

[string]$date = Get-Date -format "MM.dd.yyyy"
$Instanceid = "Testid"

[xml] $xml = gc "C:\LogFiles\$Instanceid-SQLUsers.xml"

$child = $xml.CreateElement("DatabaseName")
$child.SetAttribute('DatabaseName','$database')
$xml.SQLUsers.SQLAccount.$accountName.AppendChild($child)

$xml.save("C:\LogFiles\$Instanceid-SQLUsers_update.xml")
```

However, I receive the following error:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At D:\Scripts\AttachUserToDB_XML3.ps1:12 char:1
+ $xml.SQLUsers.SQLAccount.$accountName.AppendChild($child)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

I tried it also with innerXML, but, didn't worked.
Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Since your xml structure has multiple sqlaccount tag, you wont be able to navigate to the exact user account element.

Either change the xml structure to have single sqlaccounts and list all the users or use xpath query to retrieve the exact user element and call appendChild on it.

Comment: You're wrong. I agree that he should change the xml stucture to make it easier, but he can navigate like he already has in his sample. See my answer for an explanation to why it failed for him. Also, he could use xpath, like `$xml.SelectSingleNode("//AccountName[. = '$accountName']").parentnode` (although this is case sensitive).

Comment: Hi mate, I disagree. The reason @PávelAndrás 
`$xml.SQLUsers.SQLAccount.$accountName`
won't work is because he has **SQLAccount** element duplicated and that's why he will have to access it like array. To make it work if he removes the redundant SQLAccount and replace it with SqlAccounts and put the User elements underneath directly he can access the user element easily like
`$xml.SQLUsers.SQLAccounts.$accountName.AppendChild($child)`

Comment: I agree. I was answering your following line `Since your xml structure has multiple sqlaccount tag, you wont be able to navigate to the exact user account element. `, which is wrong because he can navigate to the right account, but he needs more logic to find it then we would prefer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your xml is badly designed. Nodes should have "standard" names so you can verify your xml against a schema. You have a `user0002`-node which is kinda useless, since this value is already specified in the `AccountName`-element. This:

```
<SQLAccount>
  <user002>
    <AccountName>user002</AccountName>
  </use002>
</SQLAccount>
```

should be simplified to something like this (since the AccountName-element already includes the username/unique value):

```
<SQLAccount>
  <AccountName>user002</AccountName>
</SQLAccount>
```

But to answer you question, there are a few things I want to point out:

1. The problem is that when you run `$xml.SQLUsers.SQLAccount.$accountName`, you get an array of two items: a null object, and your xmlelement, so you need to specify `$xml.SQLUsers.SQLAccount.$accountName[1]` to get your node. If the account doesn't exists, you still get an array of two items: two null-objects. So remember to verify that the node was found. Ex. check to see if the `AccountName`-property exists.
2. You are also creating the element wrong. Your sample does not include a `databasename`-attribute, but your script tries to create one.
3. Your script reads from one file and saves to another. So to be able to add multiple databases like you've shown in your sample, your script needs to support multiple database-names in one call.

You could try this:

```
function UpdateXML {
    param($accountName,[string[]]$database)

    $Instanceid = "Testid"

    [xml] $xml = gc "C:\LogFiles\$Instanceid-SQLUsers.xml"

    #case sensitive! easy to read
    #$accountnode = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//AccountName[. = '$accountName']").parentnode

    #case insensitive
    $accountnode = $xml.SQLUsers.SQLAccount.$accountName[1]

    #If a node for the account was found
    if($accountnode.AccountName) {
        foreach ($dbname in $database) {
            $element = $xml.CreateElement("DatabaseName")
            $element.InnerText = $dbname
            $accountnode.AppendChild($element) | Out-Null
        }

        $xml.save("C:\LogFiles\$Instanceid-SQLUsers_update.xml")
    } else {
        Write-Error "Account '$accountName' doesn't exist!"
    }
}

UpdateXML -accountName "user002" -database "database1", "database2"
```